# resizing/floating page for android

Tags: android, html, css

I'm trying to design a web form that can be easily viewed/used on computers as well as smartphones. I created a floating layout that resizes from 1000px down to 300px along with the browser window. It works fine on a computer, and from what I've been told on an iPhone. But when a user pulls it up on Android, Android simply zooms way out to view the entire 1000px page, rather than "collapsing" it to the "narrow" mode.

[link no longer active]

Do I have to use some type of browser detection to do this? Or is there a way to get Android to work like a really narrow computer web browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your meta viewport have anything for dpi?

```
<meta content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" name="viewport">
```